# error :Queue input is backward in time when to capture audio with ffmpeg

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, video, alsa, ffmpeg

Show all sound card in my pc.

```
pacmd list-sources |grep  name:
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
```

Now to capture audio playing via `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor`.

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor \
       /tmp/out.mkv
```

I encounter error info:

```
Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 3 times
[matroska @ 0x562e991d5e00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 4550, current: 4507; changing to 4550. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Add `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` input option:

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor /tmp/out.mkv
```

Note that you will likely get Vorbis audio by default for Matroska output. You can add `-c copy` if you just want to mux the input PCM audio into `.mkv` (or `.mka`).

Comment: It is no use to set the argument.

Comment: @showkey Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I still get the `Queue input is backward in time` message with that option